Spring Boot and Batch Processor Item Date field is null
Spring batch using JdbcCursorItemReader for reader. and
.setSql("select * from EMPLOYEE")
Employee entity has a Date filed
@Column(name = "CREATE_DATE_TIME")
private LocalDateTime createDateTime;

and Oracle column data type is TIMESTAMP(6)
In the Batch Processor
@Component
public class EmployeeItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Employee, EmployeeToWrite> {

    @Override
    public EmployeeToWrite process(Employee item) throws Exception {

the item createDateTime value coming as null, where in Database value there is also other columns' value fetching correctly only issue with dates fields.
also jpa repository query working fine ex: finaAll() findBy
Spring boot 3, Batch 5

Try this:
@Column(name = "CREATE_DATE_TIME", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
private LocalDateTime createDateTime;

Taken from this source.

Thanks @Bakou, I alredy tried columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP". but same issue coming null value
